# Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I am new to Ionic and created a simple application. I have installed `Android  Sdk`. And added these `Environment Variable`

I am trying to build my app using `cordova build command`command but getting  this error :-

> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

[image]
I am been searching whole day for the solution and finally ended up here.

Comment: Did you not add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in environment variables ?
Check this - https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7568583

Answer (score 4):

For linux, you'll also need to add these lines in `~/.bashrc` file

```
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/your_username/Android/Sdk'
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='/home/your_username/Android/Sdk'
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

Then check if android target is read with `cordova requirements` first.

Reference for Mac OS:

https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7568583

Answer (score 3):

Command should be `ionic platform add android` and not `cordova platform add android`

Comment: Tried that  too but say `The platform command has been renamed`

Comment: Check if path for environment variable ANDROID_HOME is correct . Also try updating latest version of Cordova -npm update -g ionic cordova

Comment: Value of path Android_Home is Installated location of android-sdk

Comment: Am I missing somethiing?

Comment: I believe it might be some version issue with your OS. Check this link once might be helpful to find out the root cause -https://www.christianengvall.se/add-android-platform-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error ...
In my case, it was occurring because of the changes in ionic CLI...

Now you need to run 'ionic cordova platform add android' (or ios) but the extension dont run this command yet...

I just insert 'cordova' in the source code of plugin (try to search the funcions that run the commands that start with 'ionic' and have to run 'cordova' together'

In the macOS, you find the source code at: 
~/.vscode/extensions/vsmobile.cordova-tools-1.2.7/out/src/debugger/cordovaDebugAdapter.js

In the Windows, the path is:
C:\Users\yourusername\.vscode\extensions\vsmobile.cordova-tools-1.2.7\out\src\debugger\cordovaDebugAdapter.js

It worked for me...